# Getting an element from a list in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
>>>one = {5974358: ('Reynolds', 'S', 'Spanish Town')}
```

what's the simplest way to get an element from the list?

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Python

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
one = {5974358: ('Reynolds', 'S', 'Spanish Town')}
print one[5974358][1]
```